# Return 404 after configure the https on Apache 2.4

Tags: apache-2.4, https, angular

I am trying to deploy a new Angular app with apache 2.4 + ubuntu 16. Angular app is the frontend app, it would call the api from backend servers.
I can visit the home page, but failed with error "The requested URL was not found on this server." when I try to visit the next page.

Here is my configurations for apache.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        ServerName xxxxxxxxx.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api
        RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/apache2_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/apache2_access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/
        ServerName xxxxxxxxx.com
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /opt/clsfd_ib/env/ssl_keys/xxxxxxxxx.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /opt/clsfd_ib/env/ssl_keys/xxxxxxxxx.com.rsa
        #SSLCertificateChainFile /opt/clsfd_ib/env/ssl_keys/xxxxxxxxx.com.pem
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combinedi

        ProxyPass /api http://YYYYYYYYYY.com:1337
        ProxyPassReverse /api http://YYYYYYYYYY.com:1337
        <Location "/api">
                Require all granted
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What is the URL you tried to access?

Comment: I can visit 'https://xxxxxxxxx.com/' but failed with 'https://xxxxxxxxx.com/reports/001'

Comment: Is that meant to be passed to your backend? You only passed URLs beginning with `/api`.

Comment: yes, it will call backend for getting the data.

Comment: You haven't configured Apache to pass them though!

Comment: I used the reverse proxy, anything wrong?
        ProxyPass /api http://YYYYYYYYYY.com:1337
        ProxyPassReverse /api http://YYYYYYYYYY.com:1337

Comment: Your URL starts with /reports, not /api !

Comment: URL is /reports, but backend call the API /api, they are not same.

Comment: That's exactly the point! You aren't handling the URL at all.

Comment: Could you help to give me an example, I really know less about the configuration for Apaceh 2.4.